# Custom Exception Filter not being hit in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I have a custom exception filter that I'm using to catch a custom exception that I wrote but for some reason when I throw my exception, it's not ever getting to the filter.  Instead I just get an error that my exception was not handled by user code.  Can anyone please provide some advice/assistance as to how I should have this set up?  Relevant code is below:

```
// controller    
[CustomExceptionFilter]
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {    
        public SomeController()
        {

        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SomeClass.SomeStaticMethod();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

that's the controller with the customexception attribute

```
// some class (where exception is being thrown)
public class SomeClass
{
    public static void SomeStaticMethod()
    {
        throw new MyCustomException("Test");
    }
}
```

that's the class (for my test) that throws the exception (I've also tried throwing it directly on the controller).

```
// Custom exception filter (want this to catch all unhandled exceptions)
public class CustomExceptionFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(MyCustomException))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

that's the custom exception filter...it's never being reached when the code is executed and the exception is thrown.  Instead I get the error mentioned above.  Everything I've read indicates that this is the proper way to set this up, but when I put breakpoints in my custom filter, it's never being hit....

What am I missing here?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've handled your error, you need to let the filter context know it has been handled. Like this:

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
```

This should be in your '// do stuff' section.

I've copied your code, and the filter is getting called fine. The only difference I made was I added the exceptionHandled code and adding my breakpoint at that line.

Comment: Hopefully you're still following this even though it's 4 days old.  I just got back to this and added your line of code inside my if block....it's never being reached as my OnException method is never being called.  Is there a flag somewhere that I need to set (maybe in web.config) or something to tell the application to handle exceptions in this filter?  I"m still getting the error on the "throw new MyCustomException("Test");" line indicating that the exception was unhandled by user code.

Comment: I didn't need to set any flags, or add anything to web.config. It just worked. When I step through in debug mode: First the exception is thrown and it breaks there. Then I press play and it goes through to my breakpoint in OnException. Have you tried stepping through in debug mode?

Comment: I assume that everything is in the same namespace and you only have one CustomExceptionFilter and CustomException.

Comment: Also, try commenting out the code that checks the exception type in case the filter is getting called but it's not matching your exception for some reason.

Comment: as it turned out, it was the debugger that was killing me.  When I just rt click the default.aspx page and 'view in browwer' I got the desired result.  I'm thinking my debug settings need some adjustment somehow?  I'm not sure how to tone it down in Visual Studio.  Thanks for your responses.  I did need the filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true so I'll mark that as the answer :)

Comment: Cool. Glad you've sorted your problem.