# How to allow MVC ActionFilter to see what the "Invalid JSON primitive" raw data is?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, filter, actionfilterattribute

I have the following action method with custom [JsonFilter] and this ActionFilterAttribute isn't called when the JSON structure for **CustomClass** sent by the client is invalid:

```
  [JsonFilter(Param = "myCustomClass", JsonDataType = typeof(CustomClass)]
  [ValidateInput(false)]
  public ActionResult MyFunction(CustomClass myCustomClass) 
  {
     //Do something ground-breaking here
  }
```

The [Json] ActionFilterAttribute code will only get called if the JSON structure passed by the client is valid. If the JSON structure sent by the client is invalid, seems the MVC framework pipeline throws the following exception and my ActionFilter logic never gets called (would like send back a special error code for the class type in error). Here is the exception I get and would like to not have these classes/events try to look at the JSON data when my action method is called:

```
Invalid JSON primitive: <reports the first character that resulting in invalid JSON format here> 
enter code here
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: .

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 

[ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: .]
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() +762458
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +360
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth) +542
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +222
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeList(Int32 depth) +379
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +325
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth) +542
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +222
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) +115
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +239
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +66
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +153
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1449
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +150
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +96
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +487
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +150
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +203
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +879
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +150
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +154
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +527
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +108
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +150
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +203
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +665
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12289467
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280
```

I also tried adding the following to the class/properties:

```
[ScriptIgnore]
```

But that too didn't work. If I remove the parameter from my action method, then my method will get a chance to look at the passed in data but I need to then access the request object for the JSON when I have a dedicated JSON Action filter to convert the JSON to C# class. **Any suggestions out there as to how to prevent the Framework from trying parse this JSON prior to my ActionFilter getting a go a it?**

Comment: Try to implement custom exception filter.

Comment: Will look into that. But upon initial inspection, it appears that this is a global filter, was hoping this can be applied at the method level with attributes noting what type of error code to throw. Thanks again, will post my updates once I have some details.

Comment: Hamlet, you were right on about your answer. Thanks a million. I used this  post for more details on implementing such a filter and it can be applied at the action method level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073925/custom-exception-filter-not-being-hit-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Hamlet, you were right on about your answer. Thanks a million. I used this  post for more details on implementing such a filter and it can be applied at the action method level: [Custom Exception Filter not being hit in asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073925/custom-exception-filter-not-being-hit-in-asp-net-mvc)